# Ruby undefined method each_slice error

Tags: ruby

I've an interesting app on GitHub. The problem is that I have an error, and that I don't know Ruby at all.

I have the error message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dmm_util-0.1.0/lib/dmm_util/fluke28x_driver.rb:274:
in `parse_readings': undefined method `each_slice' for #<DmmUtil::ByteStr:0x007ffbf38e4620> (NoMethodError)
```

In the code, there is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'serialport'
require 'enumerator'

# ...

def parse_readings(reading_bytes)
  readings = {}
  ByteStr.new(reading_bytes).each_slice(30) do |reading_arr|
    r = reading_arr.map{|b| b.chr}.join
    # All bytes parsed
    readings[get_map_value(:readingid, r, 0)] = {
                           :value => get_double(r, 2),
                           :unit => get_map_value(:unit, r, 10),
                           :unit_multiplier => get_s16(r, 12),
                           :decimals => get_s16(r, 14),
                           :display_digits => get_s16(r, 16),
                           :state => get_map_value(:state, r, 18),
                           :attribute => get_map_value(:attribute, r, 20),
                           :ts => get_time(r, 22)
    }
  end
  readings
end
```

My Ruby version is: 2.0.0p648

Comment: This is something common in Ruby as if the parameter reading_bytes, is nil value, then the result of the ByteStr.new returns also a nil value so the next part of the code is calling the method each_slice but as there are no String created from ByteStr class then you got that error. String class supports to use Enumerable if the string is correctly returned.

Comment: I have added some puts commands. reading_bytes contains 30 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the class you're invoking the `each_slice` method on a class of an unknown type. `each_slice` is an `enumerable` method, so try converting it to an array object. Give this a try:

```
     def parse_readings(reading_bytes)
      readings = {}
        bytestr = ByteStr.new(reading_bytes).chars.to_a 
         bytestr.each_slice(30) do|reading_arr|
            r = reading_arr.map{|b| b.chr}.join
            # All bytes parsed
            readings[get_map_value(:readingid, r, 0)] = {
                                   :value => get_double(r, 2),
                                   :unit => get_map_value(:unit, r, 10),
                                   :unit_multiplier => get_s16(r, 12),
                                   :decimals => get_s16(r, 14),
                                   :display_digits => get_s16(r, 16),
                                   :state => get_map_value(:state, r, 18),
                                   :attribute => get_map_value(:attribute, r, 20),
                                   :ts => get_time(r, 22)
            }
          end
          readings
      end
```

Comment: I tried your code. I have an error:  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dmm_util-0.1.0/lib/dmm_util/fluke28x_driver.rb:275: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
     enum = ByteStr.new(reading_bytes).enum_for (:each_slice, 30)
                                                             ^

Comment: Updated above. Try converting your object to an array.

Comment: I also tried it, the error message is:  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dmm_util-0.1.0/lib/dmm_util/fluke28x_driver.rb:279:in `parse_readings': undefined method `to_a' for #<DmmUtil::ByteStr:0x007fe418210f80> (NoMethodError)
  I must add that that I've found later in the code:    class ByteStr < String
    alias :each :each_byte
  end  I don't know if this is important

Comment: Ahh it appears your class is a string... you can no longer convert strings to an array... I've updated above. Hopefully this fixes the problem

Comment: Bingo! It works  I have now an other error much later. I'll see what's happening, and eventually post a new question.